# Recovering a password from a SHA3_512 value using python program

Tags: python

I am trying to recover the password from this unsalted hash: `11af05af85d7656ee0f2e3260760bccdc2af88dee449f682ab2e367003856166edc045c4164a4d543ea4a43d6dd022d3c290866f2d2a7a92a38400bd3a5f7ab0` using a python program.

I have the following code and getting this error `"TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"`

The error looks like it is coming from the line (`if hashlib.sha3_512(pwCandidate).hexdigest() == pwHashHex:`)

```
import itertools
import time
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify
import shutil
import os
from Crypto.Hash import SHA3_512

pw = input("Enter Password: ")
pw = pw.encode('utf-8')
pwHashHex = hashlib.sha3_512(pw).hexdigest()
print(pwHashHex)

def tryPassword(pwHashHex):
    start = time.time()
    
    chars = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}|:;'\",<.>/?"
    
    attempts = 0
    
    for value in range(1, 9):
        for pwCandidate in itertools.product(chars, repeat=value):
            attempts += 1
            pwCandidate = ''.join(pwCandidate)
            
            if hashlib.sha3_512(pwCandidate).hexdigest() == pwHashHex:
                end = time.time()
                distance = end - start
                return (pwCandidate, attempts, distance)

pwFound, tries, timeAmount = tryPassword(pwHashHex)
print("The password %s was cracked in %s tries and %s seconds!" % (pwFound, tries, timeAmount))
```

Comment: Do `chars = b"1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC...etc"`. Your existing code creates a string, which is Unicode, but for encryption you need a bytestring.

Comment: You would also need to use `b''.join` rather than `''.join`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the candidate just as you did the original password. `hashlib.sha3_512` does not accept a `str` argument.

```
if hashlib.sha3_512(pwCandidate.encode()).hexdigest() == pwHashHex:
```